# Python Unittest: Ensure that objects do not contain data from previous run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am using `setUp` to create a new object from a class I created. It is my understanding that this function will be executed before each test in the test case, and that this should result in *new* objects being created for each test. It seems that this is not what is happening; at least not in my tests.

Here is my class:

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, entities = []):
        self.entities = entities

    def add(self, entity: str):
        if entity not in self.entities:
            self.entities.append(entity)
```

And here are the corresponding tests:

```
import unittest
from entity import Entity

class EntityTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.entity = Entity()
        print("Starting Entites = {}".format(self.entity.entities))

    def testA(self):
        self.entity.add("Foo")
        self.assertEqual(self.entity.entities, ["Foo"])

    def testB(self):
        self.entity.add("Bar")
        self.assertEqual(self.entity.entities, ["Bar"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I would expect that `testA` and `testB` would start with new `Entity` objects. That is, I would expect `Entity.entities` to be a brand new list for each test.

I am running my tests with `python -m unittest discover -v` which results in the following output:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -v
testA (test_entity.EntityTestCase) ... Starting Entites = []
ok
testB (test_entity.EntityTestCase) ... Starting Entites = ['Foo']
FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: testB (test_entity.EntityTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/julioguzman/Sites/Foobar/test_entity.py", line 15, in testB
    self.assertEqual(self.entity.entities, ["Bar"])
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['Foo', 'Bar'] != ['Bar']

First differing element 0:
'Foo'
'Bar'

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 1:
'Bar'

- ['Foo', 'Bar']
+ ['Bar']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

As you can see, `testB` starts with the data from `testA`. This is not the desired behavior, although it may be the intended one.

How do I ensure that my objects are "clean" for each test? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, entities = []):
        self.entities = entities
```

Where the default argument is instantiated once and thus resulting in this common issue

- ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Simply modify the `__init__` to use a surrogate value and assign a brand new list if so:

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, entities=NotImplemented):
        if entities is NotImplemented:
            self.entities = []
        else:
            self.entities = entities
```

As an aside, this is one reason why unittests are written: they also test whether the class was created correctly with the expected behavior.  It was not an issue with your test when the `setUp` clearly showed that it created a brand new object - the fault lies with the implementation where it did something unexpected.